# Why is javascript recursive function returning 'undefined' even when I am returning a value

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I am looking at how to implement binary search in a javascript function and found that when I return the value and save it into a variable then when I console.log this comes as undefined.

```
const recursiveBinarySearch = (numbers, target) => {
    const midpoint = Math.floor(numbers.length / 2);

    if (numbers[midpoint] === target){
        //it does found the value and return
        return 'FOUND';

    } else if(numbers[midpoint] < target) {
        recursiveBinarySearch(numbers.slice(midpoint+1), target);

    } else {
        recursiveBinarySearch(numbers.slice(midpoint-1), target);

    }
}
var result = recursiveBinarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 100] , 8);
console.log(result); // Here is returning undefined
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing return statements?

Comment: you don't `return` the result of the recursion.

Comment: After all these years doing javascript I couldn't get my head around on that if you don't return the result of the recursive function this one will return undefined, it is not easy to see at first but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You need some `return` statements. You could omit the `else` statements as well, because if returned, it does not execure the `else` part.

```js
const recursiveBinarySearch = (numbers, target) => {
  const midpoint = Math.floor(numbers.length / 2);

  if (numbers[midpoint] === target) {
    //it does found the value and return
    return 'FOUND';

  }

  if (numbers[midpoint] < target) {
    return recursiveBinarySearch(numbers.slice(midpoint + 1), target);
  }

  return recursiveBinarySearch(numbers.slice(midpoint - 1), target);
}
var result = recursiveBinarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 100] , 8);
console.log(result); // Here is returning undefined
```

Comment: Why do you always answer questions that should be closed instead?  Is it for the reputation?  Or do you not know the reasons for closing questions?

Comment: the rep does not matter, but it is easier to show what is going wrong, than to add a comment. anway i expect that the question is being deleted at the end.

Comment: I'll certainly be voting to delete it.