# JavaScript returns undefined instead of value in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a simple function to get value from nested arrays:

```
function getVal(arr){
  var el = arr[0];
  console.log(el);
  console.log(Array.isArray(el));
  if(Array.isArray(el)){
    getVal(el);
  }else{
    return el;
  }
}
```

And I get undefined all the time. Here is the console output:

```
getVal([["a"]]);
["a"]
true
"a"
false
undefined
```

As far as I understand, when `el === "a"` condition `if(Array.isArray(el))` is satisfied and I get recursive call with `getVal("a")`, which gives undefined result. What's happening there? And why `"a"` is not returned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: recursive function returns undefined for existing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069423/javascript-recursive-function-returns-undefined-for-existing-value) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508709/javascript-recursion-function-returning-undefined)? or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480936/recursive-function-in-javascript-returns-undefined)? or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105774/why-is-javascript-recursive-function-returning-undefined-even-when-i-am-return)?

Comment: [Significance of return keyword in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610872/significance-of-return-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't return the value from the recursive function call when `Array.isArray(el)` is true. Return it like `return getVal(el);`

```js
function getVal(arr){
  var el = arr[0];
  if(Array.isArray(el)){
    return getVal(el);
  }else{
    return el;
  }
}

console.log(getVal([["a"]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
getVal(el);
```

with

```
return getVal(el);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!